# Egrepping stdout to attain specific strings

Tags: bash, grep

I was attempting to grep a command's stdout to only show the results between two strings. I wanted to print from the first case of 'Alias', to the first case of 'Until' and then have that repeat again.

stdout: ("<---" are used to just show which lines I'm trying to print)

```
foo
bar
Alias: Name                        <---
fo bar
foo bar
Valid from: Monday Until: Thu May 26 12:44:38         <---
Valid from: Tuesday Until: Fri Nov 27 22:41:01 
Alias: Another_Name                <---
Valid from: Wednesday Until: Fri Nov 27 22:41:01         <---
Valid from: Friday Until: Thu Dec 04 23:31:58
Foo bar 
bar foo
```

piped expected output:

```
Alias: Name Until: Thu May 26 12:44:38
Alias: Another_Name Until: Fri Nov 27 22:41:01
```

Things I've Tried:

```
command | egrep "Alias:*|until:*" #This also captures the second 'until's'
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You may consider this `awk` solution:

```sh
some_command |
awk '/Alias:/{p=1; printf "%s ", $0} p && sub(/^.*Until:/, "Until:") {print; p=0}'

Alias: Name Until: Thu May 26 12:44:38
Alias: Another_Name Until: Fri Nov 27 22:41:01
```

Comment: Thanks! Is it ok if you could give an explanation of your solution. I'm somewhat new to awk, itd be super helpful!

Comment: hmm tried this out. It works for the above example file, however even though the command output is basically the same as the example above, it isn't working for when the command is being piped in.

Comment: If `Alias:` and `Until:` pair appear in the same order as shown in example then this will surely work. Please show an input text for which it doesn't work and then I will investigate it.

Answer (score 0):

Not very elegant, due to the repetion of the word *Alias*, but it should work:

```
your_command | grep -E '^Alias| Until' | grep -F -A 1 Alias
```